# Archlinux not configured with iptables

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, firewall, kernel-modules

I have been trying to set up iptables on my archlinux server, however when I run `iptables -nvL` I receive the error

`iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table 'filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`

Having tried to load the modules and failing I checked to see if they were installed using modinfo and they could not be found. I was trying to run these modules `x_tables, ip_tables, ip_filter, iptable_filter, xt_tcpudp, nf_conntrack, xt_state, nf_conntrack_ipv4` Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
Having done some more research on the problem I think I may need to install the necessary modules manually. Is this something which is possible over ssh? I am not sure how to go about rebuilding the kernel.

Comment: You need to run that as user `root`. Also you are better off running `iptables-save`

Comment: All commands were run as root.

Comment: Paste the contents of `/proc/net/ip_tables_names` and `strace iptables -nvL` so we can help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I run a custom kernel, I do not know if the module needed for the `filter` table is included in the stock arch kernel. But perhaps you do not even need exactly this table. On my system, I normally just use the `nat` table.

Pass the parameter `-t` to all `iptables` invocations to select a given table, for example trying `iptables -nvLt nat`